# Linear dependency of vectors in the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

> **Q :** Find a basis for $\textsf W^0$ (the annihilator of $\textsf W$) and find $\dim(\textsf W^0)$, when  $$\textsf W = \operatorname{span}(\{\phi_0,\phi_1\}) \subseteq (\mathbb C_{\le
>  3}[x])^*$$ and $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$ for all $f\in (\mathbb C_{\le
>  3}[x])^*$.

So here's what i'm struglling with:

- $\textsf W^0 = \big( \operatorname{span}(\{\phi_0,\phi_1\}) \big)^0 = (\{\phi_0,\phi_1\})^0 = \{v\in\mathbb C_{\le3}[x] :\, \phi_0(v)=\phi_1(v)=0\}$.
- $\dim(\textsf W^0) = \dim(\mathbb C_{\le 3}[x]) - \dim(\textsf W)$.

So I need to know the linear dependency of $\varphi_0,\varphi_1$ to conclude how many vectors spans $\textsf W^0$.
Now I can express $\phi_0,\phi_1$ as :

- $\phi_0(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=a\cdot\phi_0(1)+b\cdot\phi_0(x)+c\cdot\phi_0(x^2)+d\cdot \phi_0(x^3)=a$
- $\phi_1(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=a+b+c+d$

since $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$. (Plese let me know if this use is right, because $\phi_0(1)=1(0)$ feels weird to me, but makes sense).

From here, how do I find the linear dependency?

Comment: why do you keep a $0$ under $\{{\phi_0,\phi_1\}}_0 ?$

Comment: What do you mean by "Find a basis for ... $\dim(W_0)$"?

Comment: @Pastudent The subscript indicates that one should take the annihilator subspace.

Comment: to express that the annihilator of $Span(\{\phi_0,\phi_1\})$ = the annihilator of $\{\phi_0,\phi_1\}$. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk - I mean find $dim(W_0)$, not a basis for $dim(W_0)$. I made the changes to be even more clear.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense, don't know why I kept misreading that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a more general situation. Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in V^*$.

If $W=\operatorname{span}\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$, then
$$
W^0=\{v\in V: \alpha_k(v)=0,\quad i=1,2,\dots,n\}
$$
(prove it). There's no need to check whether $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is linearly independent or not.

In your case,
$$
W^0=\{f\in\mathbb{C}_{\le3}[x]:\phi_0(f)=0,\phi_1(f)=0\}
$$
If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, the conditions read
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0=0 \\[5px]
a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=0
\end{cases}
$$
By the way, since $\dim W^0=2$, you can conclude that $\dim W=4-2=2$, so $\{\phi_0,\phi_1\}$ is linearly independent.

A basis for $W^0$ is $\{x^2-x,x^3-x\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. 
Regarding the linear independence. Let's just verify the definition : 
Our set $W_0$ is lin $\iff$ ($\sum_{i=0}^{1} \alpha_i \, \phi_i = 0 (\alpha_i \text{ being polynomials}) \implies \alpha_i = 0 )$ 
As you said, we indeed have : 
$\phi_0(f)= a$ and  $\phi_1(f)= a + b + c + d$ 
By injecting this into the lin formula : 
$$ (\alpha_0+\alpha_1)a + \alpha_1(b+c+d) = 0 \\ $$
$\alpha_1(b+c+d) = 0$ is only satisfied for $\alpha_1 = 0$ (since all $a,b,c,d$ are in $\mathbb{C}$ and can take any value) $\implies$ $\alpha_0a = 0 \, \forall a\in \mathbb{C}$ which in turn implies $\alpha_0$ is the null polynomial.
That is it for linear independency.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. I'm not trying to find $W_0$ is lin. independent (It's actually isn't, as a subspace of $\mathbb C_{\le 3}[X]$), but to show $\{\phi_0,\phi_1\}$ is lin. depnedent\independent. Also, I don't understand $\alpha_i\phi_i$, since they are both vectors (one is a polynomial over the complex and the second is a linear functional in the dual space). Can you elaborate?

Comment: To be more exact I don't understand why you take $\sum_{i=0}^1\alpha_i\phi_i$ as a linear combination, as $\alpha_i,\phi_i$ are vectors